# React-Query useQuery and axios.get with a param always return data:undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-query

I've this hook:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

const fetchCartPreview = (cartId, userId) => {
  console.log("Init query");
  axios
    .get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/carts/${cartId}/checkout_preview`,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        params: { user_id: userId },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => console.log("Response from hook", response.data));
};

export default function useCartPreview(cartId, userId) {
  return useQuery(
    ["cart_preview", cartId, userId],
    async () => {
      const data = await fetchCartPreview(cartId, userId)
      return data
    },
    { onSuccess:  console.log("Finish query") }
  );
}
```

The console.log(response.data) it's ok, the problem is that the useQuery, onSuccess, returns data: undefined and T don't know why..

[Console.log in the component that calls the hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZg2W.png)

Thank you!

Comment: You are not returning anything from `fetchCartPreview()`, therefore `data` will be `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Is it still not working if you are returning `response.data` from `fetchCartPreview` ?

Can you try adjusting your function like this:

```
const fetchCartPreview = (cartId, userId) => {
  console.log("Init query");
  axios
    .get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/carts/${cartId}/checkout_preview`,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json"
        },
        params: { user_id: userId }
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Response from hook", response.data);
      return response.data;
    });
};
```

Comment: Tank you orotype but it still not working, I've tried de same before.
It seems that the react-query onSuccess status execute before the axios response.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. `onSuccess` needs to be a function:

```
{ onSuccess: () => console.log("Finish query") }
```

2. You need to actually *return* something from your queryFn. By doing:

```
axios
    .get(url)
    .then((response) => console.log("Response from hook", response.data));
```

you are transforming your promise in the `.then` part, logging the data, but then you return `undefined`, which will put `undefined` in the react-query cache. if you must log in the query fn, you have to make sure to actually return something from `.then`:

```
axios
  .get(url)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
    return response //or return response.data
  })
```

but it is better to keep logging out of the queryFn and use the `onSuccess` callback for that.